# Armazenamento da soma de matrizes em vetor

Tags: c, matriz

Essa função que criei precisa calcular a **soma** de cada coluna da matriz e armazenar em uma posição do vetor. Porém, não está dando o resultado desejado, acho que pode ser dentro do terceiro`for`.

Alguem pode me ajudar em relação a guardar o resultado da soma da matriz no vetor?

```
void soma(int mat[] [MAX], int n, int m, int v[])  
{

int i,j,soma=0;
int res, x=0;


for (i = 0; i < n; i ++)
{
    for ( j = 0; j < m ;j ++)
    { 
        for(x=0; x < m; x++)
        {
            soma=soma+ mat[i][j];
            res[v]=soma;
            printf(" %d\n",res );
        }
    }
}



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você percorre a matriz em duas dimensões, linha e coluna, então só faz sentido haver dois `for`s.

O vetor onde você guarda o resultado é percorrido junto com a coluna, contendo a soma dos valores em cada linha, e portanto, faz sentido percorrer primeiro as colunas e depois as linhas.

Na sua implementação, a variável `soma` está acumulando os valores de todos os elementos da matriz, e não acumulando-os por coluna. Além disso, como há um terceiro `for`, cada valor será contabilizado `m` vezes.

Acho que ao invés de `res[v]`, seria melhor você usar `v[res]`. Aliás, a variável `res` não tem seu valor definido em lugar algum, então seria `v[alguma_outra_coisa]`.

O que você queria era isso:

```
void soma(int mat[][MAX], int n, int m, int v[]) {
    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
        v[j] = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { 
            v[j] += mat[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Procurei sobre armazenamento de somas de matrizes em vetores e achei o site **GUJ**.

```
for(i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
   for(j = 0; j < 5; j++ {
       vetorA[j] += matriz[i][j];
       vetorB[i] += matriz[i][j];
```

Fonte: http://www.guj.com.br/t/armazenar-soma-de-linhas-de-matriz-em-vetor/361757

> **Observação:** não formatei o código, apenas peguei a parte lógica da resposta de um problema onde alguém queria armazenar o valores da
>   mesma maneira que você. Dê uma lida a mais no site por via das
>   dúvidas.